# Match multiple result from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, formula

Currently I need to find a number that may appear in three different workbooks, I know how to find if there is only one workbook and coding below:

`=IF(INDEX([example.xlsx]sheet1!F:F,MATCH(B8,[example.xlsx]sheet1!A:A,0),1)>0,"yes","no")`

And if three workbook the formula should be like below:

`=IF(INDEX([example.xlsx]sheet1!F:F,MATCH(B8,[example1.xlsx]sheet1!A:A,0),1)>0,"yes",=IF(INDEX([example.xlsx]sheet1!F:F,MATCH(B8,[example2.xlsx]sheet1!A:A,0),1)>0,"yes",=IF(INDEX([example.xlsx]sheet1!F:F,MATCH(B8,[example3.xlsx]sheet1!A:A,0),1)>0,"yes","no")))`

However, Actually if the ans is yes, I need to lookup 2 other columns from these 3 different workbook, and if the column is yes, need to return another value.

Comment: Doint MATCH functions against external files is s l o w. I would advise to pull in the data into your workbook using an external connection and do the MATCH against the pulled data.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but in case, it's not allow to do so..